# Lua Find a String that may have Spaces in a String

Tags: lua, pattern-matching

How do I find the substring Joy-Con (R) in the joysticks string variable?

How do i find any substring in the joysticks variable?

```
function love.load()
    joysticks = "Joy-Con (R) Joy-Con (L)"   
end
function love.joystickadded( joystick )
    if not joysticks:find( joystick:getName() ) then
        print("not supported")
    end
end
```

Comment: `if joysticks:find("Joy-Con (R)", 1, true) then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem XY:

1. Problem isn't in spaces but in `-` and `()`.
2. It isn't correct way to check is anything allowed.

Real solution:

```
function love.load()
    joysticks = {
        ['Joy-Con (R)'] = true
        ['Joy-Con (L)'] = true
    }
end
function love.joystickadded( joystick )
    if not joysticks[joystick:getName()] then
        print("not supported")
    end
end
```

You make array where indexes are allowed values (joysticks) and  check exact match. There is a some pros:

1. It is much faster.
2. It give you EXACT match (`Joy-Co` will not match).

Use `%` to escape `-` or `()` (e.g., `%-`).